# Como mostrar contenido HTML usando un Filter en Vue Js

Tags: vue.js

Me encuentro desarrollando un proyecto personal con Vue.js y tengo la duda de como puedo mostrar etiquetas html. Me explico:

Para mostrar mi tabla tengo el siguiente código

```
<tr v-for="project in projects.data" :key="project.id">
  <td>{{ project.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ project.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ project.initialDate }}</td>
  <td>{{ project.finalDate }}</td>
  <td>{{project.status | ActivePro}}</td>
  <td>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="far fa-edit green fa-lg iconom"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" @click="deleteProject(project.id)">
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt red fa-lg iconom"></i>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Los filtros que tengo son estos

```
Vue.filter('ActivePro', function(text){
  if(text == '0') return 'Inactivo'
  if(text == '1') return 'Activo'
  if(text == '2') return 'Pausado'
  if(text == '3') return 'Terminado'  
})
```

Funcionan bien pero me gustaría que en vez de mostrar una palabra, me muestre un icono de FontAwessome, por ejemplo:

```
if(text == '1') return '<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>'
```

Dado que ya no se usa {{{}}} en Vue, según lo que he leido hay que usar *v-html*, el cual lo usé de la siguiente forma:

```
<td v-html="project.status | ActivePro"></td>
```

Esto me va a mostrar el valor entero que traigo de mi base de datos que corresponde al `status`, no me está aplicando el filtro.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede acceder a la propiedad [$options](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options) para acceder al Filtro, en forma de método y poder renderizar utilizando la directiva [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

```js
Vue.filter('ActivePro', function(text){
  if(text == '0') return '<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>'
  if(text == '1') return '<i class="fa fa-user"></i>'
  if(text == '2') return '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>'
})

var app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data : {
    projects :  [
      {id : 1 , name : 'Dev',status  : 0},
      {id : 2, name : 'Joel',status  : 1},
      {id : 3, name : 'StackOverFlow',status  : 2},
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <table>
        <tr v-for="project in projects" :key="project.id">
            <td>{{ project.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ project.name }}</td>
            <td v-html="$options.filters.ActivePro(project.status)"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Esta opción me gustó, lo había pensado también usando un v-if en el **id** pero son un poco más lineas de código. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar un método que devuelve el icono y este se encuentre amarrado a la clase:

**Template**

```
<tr v-for="project in projects.data" :key="project.id">
  <td>{{ project.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ project.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ project.initialDate }}</td>
  <td>{{ project.finalDate }}</td>
  <td>
    <i :class="getProjectIcon(project.status)"></i>        
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="far fa-edit green fa-lg iconom"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" @click="deleteProject(project.id)">
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt red fa-lg iconom"></i>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Script**

```
methods: {
  getProjectIcon(status) {
    let icon = ''
    if(status === '1') {
      icon = 'fas fa-check-circle'
    }
    // Digitas los condicionales para el resto de estados
    return icon
  }
}
```